# Why does a polynomial which shares a factor with $x^5 - x$ modulo 3 necessarily also share a factor with $-1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields

My question regards a very specific part of an example in Chapter 14.8 of Dummit and Foote (page 641, image shown below) in which the authors are computing the Galois group of $f(x) = x^5 - x - 1$ over $\mathbb Q$. They want to prove $f(x)$ is irreducible modulo 3 in order to show the Galois group over $\mathbb Q$ contains a $5$-cycle. To rule out a factorization consisting of an irreducible quadratic and a cubic, they provide the following justification:

> [If $f(x)$ had an irreducible quadratic factor modulo 3 then] it would have a factor in common with $x^9 - x$ (which is the product of all irreducible polynomials of degrees 1 and 2 over $\mathbb F_3$), hence a factor in common with either $x^4 - 1$ or $x^4 + 1$, hence a factor in common with either $x^5 - x$ or $x^5 + x$, **hence a factor in common with either $-1$ or $2x + 1$.**

I understand this reasoning up until the final phrase. **Why does sharing a factor with $x^5 - x$ or $x^5 + x$ modulo $3$ imply sharing a factor with $-1$ or $2x - 1$?**

A more general question regarding this example was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270805/question-on-an-example-from-galois-theory-j-s-milne), but it was never answered and is less specific.

[image: A screenshot of the example in question]

Comment: Answer: because $f(x) = x^5 - x - 1$.

Comment: Why is $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a-kb,b)$?

Comment: $\,g\mid x^4\!-\!1,\ x^5\!-\!x\!-\!1\,\Rightarrow\, g\mid x(x^4\!-\!1)-(x^5\!-\!x\!-\!1) = 1,\,$ i.e. $\,g\mid f,f'\Rightarrow g\mid f'\bmod f,\,$ the reduction step of the euclidean algorithm. Generally $\,g\mid f,f'\iff g\mid\gcd(f,f').\,$ It's easier to work $\!\bmod g,\,$ i.e. in $\,\Bbb F_9\,$ as in the linked dupe. $\ \ $

Comment: Ahh, one should work mod $g$. Makes complete sense. Thanks for clearing it up and for answering the question a second time @Bill Dubuque!